# UI unable to update

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I've got a resource-heavy method which takes a few seconds to execute. Thus I have decided to invoke it within a task so as to display a waiting icon while the task is carried out.

What I've done is called the `imgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` before creating a task, and then creating the task. Once the task is complete, I then call `imgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`.

For some reason, the image never collapses and stays visible indefinitely. It is a very strange issue which is quite easy to recreate. This is all the code which I've got, and I really can't see what I've done wrong:

```
imgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

var validityTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExpensiveMethod(param1,param2));

                        validityTask.ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
                        {
                            bool isvalid = validityTask.Result;

                            if (isvalid)
                            {
                                //Do something to UI
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //DO something to UI
                            }

                            imgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

As the code demonstrates, I am trying to show the `imgLoading` image while the task is carried out, and the hide the icon when the task is complete. With this current code, the icon remains visible even after the task is complete.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's when the task is complete so that the image is hidden once again - it is set to visible before the task

Comment: There is only one `Task` as such. I've got the main UI thread, and then the other task. Before starting the task for the expensive method, I just call a simple visibility propery on the icon, as shown in the edited code

Comment: Try out `Dispatcher.Current.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
{
  imgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
});            
`

Comment: @sll - instead of which part should i place that?

Comment: @sll - Just tried it, to no avail. The icon still remains there

Comment: @sll - that approach is what I carried out in the first place though

Comment: @sll none of the approaches seem to work :/

Comment: @DotNET It's strange... I tried to use your code and it works. My ExpensiveMethod doesn't take two params (it's just Thread.Sleep) and I don't check validityTask.Result, but it works. Image displayed, then Thread.Sleep(2000) in ExpensiveMethod and then image is Collapsed.

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix - I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. It just doesn't work

Comment: `validityTask.Result` could be throwing.  Try moving the `Visibility` set to above the other work.  Also, do you have global exception handlers wired up?

Comment: @yzorg - As far as I know, it is not throwing an exception as all the proceeding code is being executed.

Comment: IIUC accessing WPF UI object from a background thread will throw an exception (default behavior, might be possible to turn off from config).  Again, if you had try/catch for any code at a thread boundary you probably would have found this faster.  :)

Comment: Don't thank me, vote up my comment.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've managed to solve the problem. Posting this here incase it might help someone in the future. My problem was that the block wasn't even entering at all apparently. The solution was to remove all UI code from the task, and it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of reading the `Result` property of the `validityTask`, read it from `previousTask`.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx) a link to an example on MSDN showing the continuation accessing the `Result` property in this manner.

Comment: It's maybe why it worked for me, when I tried without checking result :D

Comment: Both variables refer to the same `Task` object, so this won't ever change how the code runs.  It helps you avoid a closure, which adds a minute performance improvement, but as the value of the closed over variable never changes, it's not a *functional* change.